# add google ads in the middle of content page

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I would like to add google ads after the first paragraph on every page on my wiki. 
I have a code that checks if a tag is there, if it isn't then the tag is added and this tag calls the code for the google ads. 
However, **the rest of the text on the page is not showing after the ads.** 
This is my code: (based on the AdsWhereever extension)

```
  $wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'AdsSetup'; $wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'][] = 'CheckHasTag';
  function AdsSetup( &$parser ) {
     $parser->setHook( 'ads', 'AdsRender' );
      return true;}

    function AdsRender($input, $args ) {    
        $input ="";  $url = array(); global $wgOut;

        $ad['goo1'] = '<html><br><script type="text/javascript">
        google_ad_client = "xxx";
        google_ad_width = 728;
        google_ad_height = 90;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script><br></html>';
   $media = $args['media'];
   return $ad[$media];
        }


         // check if content has <goo1> tag
          function CheckHasTag($editPage){global $wgOut;
           $wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript">
           var editTextboxText = document.getElementById("wpTextbox1").value;
                var searchFor = "goo1";
                           var searchResult = editTextboxText.search(searchFor);
                if(searchResult == -1){
                var a = editTextboxText;
                var b = "\n<ads media=goo1>\n";
                var findP = "\n"; 
                var p = editTextboxText.search(findP);
                var position = p;
    document.getElementById("wpTextbox1").value = a.substr(0, position) + b + a.substr(position);
       }</script>');
       return true;
       }
```

Comment: What works, and what doesn't? E.g., does `editTextboxText` contain the right text, when you try it? Does `position` have the value you expected? (That variable `p` seems a bit redundant, btw...)

Also: Your extension relies on [$wgRawHtml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) being set to true in LocalSettings.php, I guess (judging from the use of `<html>`. That can be very dangerous on a public site. You should probably look for another solution!

Comment: The code works fine. The tag <ads=goo1> is added and the ads show. However the text that comes after the ads is not being displayed. I think  return $ad[$media]; could be preventing a.substr(position) from running. This is what I'm stuck on.

Comment: I'm really confused, `return $ad[$media];` is something that's happening in the backend, how would that be related to the javascript `substr` part? Also, they are being run at completely different occasions! (And if `a.substr` didn't run, you wouldn't see the ads at all.)
Did you use your console to check the value of `a`, `position` and `b` respectively?

 And are you _sure_ that you are using  `$wgRawHtml`, so that the javascript doesn't just cut off your page at the bottom of the ad, leaving nothing else there?

Comment: console.log(a.substring(position)); gives the correct output in the console so everything seems to be working. I'm not sure what you meant by 'And are you sure that you are using  $wgRawHtml, so that the javascript doesn't just cut off your page at the bottom of the ad, leaving nothing else there?' This may be the issue. I have $wgRawHtml='true' and I'm using your code below so I don't know if i need it. How do I test this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was missing a / in the tag which was why the rest of the text wasn't being displayed! 
var b = "\n\n"

Answer (score 2):

Your code relies on `$wgRawHtml` being set to true in `LocalSettings.php`. (This, by the way, is a huge security risk, and should never be used in public wikis.) If you did not set 
`$wgRawHtml` to true, the last output of your tag function will be `</html>`, that will cause the browser to stop parsing the page, and produce no further output.

Something like this would probably work, without having to use the html-tag:

```
function AdsRender( $input, $args, $parser, $frame ) {

    $output = '<div id="googlead"><script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "xxx";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script></div>';
    return array( $output, "markerType" => 'nowiki' );
}
```

Btw, you have a lot of garbage in you example, it's easier to help you if you remove code that is not being used (like `$url = array(); global $wgOut;` etc)

Comment: I got the errror: Detected bug in an extension! Hook CheckHasTag failed to return a value; should return true to continue hook processing or false to abort.
Backtrace:
#0 ./ks::run('EditPage::showE...', Array)
#1 ./includes/EditPage.php(1741): wfRunHooks('EditPage::showE...', Array)
#2 ./includes/EditPage.php(401): EditPage->showEditForm()
#3 ./includes/actions/EditAction.php(51): EditPage->edit()
#4 ./includes/Wiki.php(427): EditAction->show()
#5 ./includes/Wiki.php(304): MediaWiki->performAction(Object(Article))
#6 ./includes/Wiki.php(536): MediaWiki->performRequest()
...: MediaWiki->main()

Comment: @LTech Ok, that means that you have changed something in `CheckHasTag`, so that it doesn't return true anylonger. Make sure it does!

Comment: Great your code inserts the google ads but it also does not show any text after the ad. I still have the same issue. I'm using your function AdsRender and the original  function CheckHasTag from the question. Why would this be? $wgRawHtml= "true"; in local settings and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: There is an console message 'Exception thrown by mediawiki.searchSuggest: Cannot call method 'test' of undefined ' load.php?debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=20121…:151